# setOnClickListener and setOnLongClickListener don't work at the same time

Tags: java, android

setOnClickListener and setOnLongClickListener do not work at the same time. When I remove one, the other works and vice versa.

In addition, I will say that if the first line of the code is changed to `childRelativeLayout.setVisibility (View.GONE);` then parentRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener does not work at all.

```
        childRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation slide_down = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_down);
    Animation slide_up = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.slide_up);

    parentRelativeLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (childRelativeLayout.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
                childRelativeLayout.startAnimation(slide_down);
                slide_down.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        childRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }
                });
            } else {
                childRelativeLayout.startAnimation(slide_up);
                slide_up.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        childRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

and onLongClick

```
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            mBuilder.setTitle("Edytuj zadanie");

            LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            @SuppressLint("InflateParams") View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.daily_alertdialog, null, false);

            //here is code...

            mBuilder.setView(mView);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = mBuilder.create();
            alertDialog.show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

parentRelativeLayout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/parentRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8sp"
    android:paddingStart="8sp"
    android:paddingEnd="8sp"
    android:paddingBottom="4sp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/goal_list_name_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="22sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        tools:text="Cel 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/category_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/goal_list_name_text_view"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Kategoria: xyz" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/goal_list_name_text_view"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="Miejsce wykonania:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/goal_list_name_text_view"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="14 luty 2018" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/date_text_view"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/goal_list_name_text_view"
        android:textColor="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:text="16:00" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

childRelativeLayout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/childRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/parentRelativeLayout"
    android:layout_margin="4sp"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    tools:ignore="Orientation"
    android:visibility="gone">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/childView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dip"
        android:background="#f5000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/plusDayTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/oneDay"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/doneTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="2sp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:text="@string/done"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

slide_down.xml

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="-60%"
    android:toYDelta="0" />
```

slide_up.xml

```
<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-60%" />
```

Comment: what file layout.xml?

Comment: @Chanh I added for you

Comment: Create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There's a bunch of other code that may or may not contribute to your issue (everything inside the listeners). Start by crating a small side project that only ever works with on click listener and on long click listener. Log everything. This may even help you solving this on your own.

Comment: Thank you! By removing the first part of the problem, I saw that the onLongClickListener method is used for itemView - I created it much earlier, when I did not have the ParentRelativeLayout field yet. If I changed the itemView to ParentRelativeLayout everything works fine. It was a silly oversight :)

Answer (score 1):

Your `onLongClick` is returning `true` indicating to the OS that the event has been handled and no other click events should be called. Try changing that value to `false`, should fix your problem.

Comment: I've set it there, true. Previously, instead of onClickeListener, I had onTouchListener - then both controls were running at the same time. I'm not sure if it works like you say. Answering a question - I changed to false. It still does not work.